# Relationship between a^x and e^(bx)

Tags: exponential-function

Is it true that any exponential $a^x$ can be represented using $e^{bx}$, assuming a suitable choice for b? For example, if we were to consider $y = 2^x$, what would be the equivalent $y = e^{bx}$ that gives the same curve as $2^x$? In my empirical studies, by plotting both functions, I can seem to always find a value for b that will give a curve $e^{bx}$ that looks like any $a^x$. This would make sense since growth functions are described using $e^{bx}$, hence $e^{bx}$ should be flexible enough to represent any exponential. Is this correct, and if so, what is the relationship between $a^x$ and $e^{bx}$?

Another way of asking is if I had an exponential such as $3^x$, that would be the value of $b$ in the equivalent $e^{bx}$?

Comment: I think I just figured it out, b = ln (a), all I did was set a^x= e^{bx), take log on both sides, then solve for b in which case I get ln (a). Correct?

Comment: Probably this question is essentially a duplicate, but if $a^x = e^{bx} = (e^b)^x$, then $a = e^b$, so *by definition* $b = \log a$, where $\log$ is the natural logarithm function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm

Comment: That's right.$ $

Comment: There's a minor problem when $a\le0$

Comment: Yes, I can see now.

Comment: @PM2Ring - When dealing with real numbers, for $a < 0, a^x$ is only defined when $x$ is an integer. If you allow complex numbers for logarithm and exponent, then for $a < 0, \ln a = \ln |a| + \pi i$ (at least that is the most common definition), and $a^x = e^x\ln a$ still holds for integer $x$. (And for some non-integer $x$, but there are limitations.)